# How can i get my code to work correctly? user input is not working with if, elif, and else

Tags: python, if-statement, input

if, elif, and else are not working with my inputs correctly. I am trying to make it so you have to pass all three questions to gain access to my fake club. but the problem is if you answer the first two questions incorrectly and the third one correctly, you still gain access to the club. also, this is an assignment for school, and my teacher said i was missing a heading, and my if statements contained no logical statements to actually weed out or accept potential users. please, help.

```
def main():
    age = input("are you younger than 21?")
    game = input("what is the game of the day?")
    cool = input("what do you think about school?") 
    
    print("Welcome to Kidz Only.")
    print("are you cool enough to enter?")
    
    if( age == "yes"):
        print("question one is done.")
    if ( game == "super mario bros"):
        print("question two is through.")    
    if ( cool == "i have mixed feelings"):
        print("question three is complete.")
        print("You have passed the quiz. Welcome to Kidz Only!")
        
    else:
        print("Sorry, but you may not enter Kidz Only.")
        
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The last if is tied to the else statement so even if the first two are wrong and the last one is correct, it will allow you to enter. A better logic would be to have conditionals for each of those requirements.

```
def main():
    age = input("are you younger than 21?")
    game = input("what is the game of the day?")
    cool = input("what do you think about school?") 
    
    print("Welcome to Kidz Only.")
    print("are you cool enough to enter?")
    
    hasAge = False
    hasGame = False
    hasCool = False

    if( age == "yes"):
        hasAge = True
        print("question one is done.")
    if ( game == "super mario bros"):
        hasGame = True
        print("question two is through.")    
    if ( cool == "i have mixed feelings"):
        hasCool = True
        print("question three is complete.")
        
    if (hasAge and hasGame and hasCool):
        print("You have passed the quiz. Welcome to Kidz Only!")
    else:
        print("Sorry, but you may not enter Kidz Only.")
        
main()
```

Although this results in a more lengthy code, it helps you see the logic better

Answer (score 0):

Reason to that would be because you are saying only if `( cool == "i have mixed feelings")` then display you are allowed to join the `"cool kids"`.
You can also shorten your code by using `and`.

```
def main():
    age = input("are you younger than 21?")
    game = input("what is the game of the day?")
    cool = input("what do you think about school?") 
    
    print("Welcome to Kidz Only.")
    print("are you cool enough to enter?")
    
    if( age == "yes") and (game == "super mario bros") and ( cool == "i have mixed feelings"):
        print("question three is complete.")
        print("You have passed the quiz. Welcome to Kidz Only!")
        
    else:
        print("Sorry, but you may not enter Kidz Only.")
        
main()
```